# C# How to reduce the size of the stream (image)

Tags: c#, android, image

All I have is the `Stream` of the file (the file is `image/jpeg` type). I want to reduce the quality of the image (example: original 2MB -> 200KB).

```
var contentStream = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return _MediaFile.GetStream(); });

newImg.Source = contentStream;

_ReportModel.Add(new ReportPicture()
{
    Id = layout.Id,
    Path = _MediaFile.Path,
    Content = _MediaFile.GetStream()
});
```

Before I upload the `_ReportModel` to my server using REST API, I want to reduce the size of the `Content` which contains the stream of the read image (type jpeg).

I need something like:

```
private Stream ReduceStreamSize(Stream oldStream)
{
    var reducedStream = //doSomething(oldStream);
    return reducedStream;
}
```

How can I do this?

---

### Update

I have tried this:

```
public Stream CompressImage(string imagePath)
    {
        try
        {

            // BitmapFactory options to downsize the image
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
            o.InSampleSize = 6;
            // factor of downsizing the image

            FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open);
            //Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
            BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
            inputStream.Close();

            // The new size we want to scale to
            int REQUIRED_SIZE = 75;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.OutWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                            o.OutHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.InSampleSize = scale;
            inputStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open);

            Bitmap selectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(inputStream, null, o2);
            inputStream.Close();

            FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open);

            selectedBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, outputStream);

            return outputStream;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But the image is not showing. There must be an error while compressing it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to resize the image or reduce the quality of the image?

Comment: You will need to re-encode the image & modify the quality - this link may be useful as a starting point : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter.aspx Note that to reduce the size by 90% you will end up with a very poor image as this link may show : https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-jpeg.html.